# Rename dataframe in Python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename a dataframe in each iteration of my for loop. For column "item" in the "data" dataframe, I would like to generate dataframes up to the number of unique items in "item" column.

```
for item in data.item.unique():
    data+"item" = data[data["item"] == item]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary:

```
frames = {}
for item in data['item'].unique():
    frames[item] = data[data['item'] == item]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can just use `groupby`:

```
frames = {k:d for k,d in data.groupby('item')}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is use dictionaries.

Your answer is this:

```
for i in data.item.unique():
    globals()[f'data{i}'] = data[data["item"] == i]
```